# How to fix "Exception - Call to a member function customdata() on null" error?

Tags: plugins, moodle, pdf.js, moodle-api

I'm importing a PDF Viewer into Moodle to view the PDF files online without downloading it. This error code `Exception - Call to a member function customdata() on null` appears when I am trying to save the files uploaded.

How do I fix this?

```
function pdfjsfolder_cm_info_dynamic(cm_info $cm) {
// The field 'customdata' is filled in only if folder is to be
// shown inline.
if ($cm_info->customdata()) {
    $cm->set_no_view_link();
   }
}

/*** Overwrites the content in the course-module object with the folder files list
 * if folder.display == FOLDER_DISPLAY_INLINE.
 *
 * @param cm_info $cm
 */
function pdfjsfolder_cm_info_view(cm_info $cm) {
global $PAGE, $DB;

if ($cm->uservisible &&
        $cm_info->customdata() &&
        has_capability('mod/pdfjsfolder:view', $cm->context)) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/locallib.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

$cm_info object not available in the scope of "pdfjsfolder_cm_info_view" function, as per code you provided above.

Replace $cm_info with $cm.